# Contenteditable div doesn't focus on iPad using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: ios, reactjs, ipad, onfocus

I'm working on a React app that includes contenteditable divs. I'm trying to implement a feature where clicking a button toggles the editing state of the div, and then the div is automatically focused using requestAnimationFrame. The code I have works fine on desktop and Android devices, but on iPad the focus doesn't seem to work reliably. Here's the code I'm using:

```js
function Edit({wait}){
  const [isEditing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="box">
      <h1>{isEditing&&<>Editable </>}Content</h1>

      <div
        contentEditable={isEditing}
        ref={async (element) => {
          if (!element) {
            return;
          }

          if (!isEditing) {
            return;
          }
          
          await wait();

          element.focus();
        }}
      >
        Foo <b>bar</b>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setEditing(!isEditing)
        }}
        className="button"
      >
        Toggle edit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}



function App() {
  return (
    <div className="box">
      <Edit wait={()=>void(0)} />
      <Edit wait={forAnimationFrame} />
     </div>
  );
}
```

This works fine on desktop and Android devices, but on iPad/iPhone the focus doesn't seem to work reliably - **it does not trigger the keyboard**. I've tried a few different approaches, including using **setTimeout** instead of **requestAnimationFrame**, using the click event instead of touchstart, and removing the delay entirely, but nothing seems to work consistently on iPad. Can anyone suggest a solution or provide some guidance on what might be causing this issue? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Here is the codepen sample https://codepen.io/hejny/pen/abRZxLm

Comment: PS: iPad even does something like focus, but doesn't show the keyboard - and that's the problem.